# Bayesian hypothesis testing and NHST - Which is better

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, bayesian

i've seen a lot of approach for hypothesis testing and i wonder if some test (mainly those coming from frequentist inference) like the null hypothesis testing are still relevants today. I've seen some articles saying that nowadays bayesian hypothesis testing is more stronger, but can this approach replace the NHST or are they suited for different kind of situations ?